# Is mathematical induction the only known example of a higher-order logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, higher-order-logic

Mathematical induction is one well known and widely cited example of a **second-order logic**.

I was wondering whether there are **other examples** of arguments involving higher-order logic in any branch of mathematics (well, except the formal logic itself, where examples would be trivial)?

Comment: An argument that uses the completeness property of the reals might qualify.

Comment: What does "Mathematical induction is one well known and widely cited example of a second-order logic." mean? I can't understand anything of your question. Do you want to say that mathematical induction is better expressed as a second-order axiom, rather than a scheme of first-order axioms?

Comment: **Can** it be expressed in terms of first-order logic?

Comment: @AndréNicolas What's the quantified property / relation there?

Comment: @LeoHeinsaar "**Can** it be expressed in FOL?" Sort of: as an axiom *schema*. @ OP: Any principle that has to be asserted as an axiom schema is a candidate. Examples: the Comprehension axiom in set theory, the Separation axiom in set theory, torsion-free condition for groups, or simply the condition that the domain of a model be infinite.

Comment: So note that the short answer to your question in your comment is "No, because the first-order axiom schema cannot fully capture the second-order full semantics."

Answer (score 3):

The induction you are referring to is the (single) second-order induction axiom for second-order Peano Arithmetic, which says:
$\def\imp{\Rightarrow}$

> "$\forall pred\ P\ ( P(0) \land \forall n\ ( P(n) \imp P(n+1) ) \imp \forall n\ ( P(n) ) )$"

and this is of course how most people think of induction (and is also the original formulation by Peano). This is second-order because it quantifies over predicates, which is not allowed in first-order logic. There is another formal system called first-order Peano Arithmetic, and in logic this is what is called PA. Of course PA has no second-order induction axiom, but instead has a whole set of first-order axioms, one for each first-order predicate, which is called an induction schema:

> "$P(0) \land \forall n\ ( P(n) \imp P(n+1) ) \imp \forall n\ ( P(n) )$" for any first-order predicate $P$.

The difference is crucial. There are at least two possible second-order semantics. Commonly second-order logic is interpreted with full semantics, where quantification over predicates ranges over all possible predicates, even if the predicate cannot be expressed by a formula. The second-order induction axiom then is extremely powerful, because it essentially ranges over the entire powerset of natural numbers. In contrast the first-order axiom schema only has countably many axioms, and so it 'controls' only countably many predicates and does not 'really know' the whole powerset, or in other words it 'only sees' the definable sets of natural numbers.

One might think that perhaps the distinction does not matter, but that is simply false. Second-order Peano Arithmetic is categorical, meaning that there is a unique model up to isomorphism. First-order Peano Arithmetic (PA) on the other hand is not even countably-categorical, meaning that it is not true that there is a unique countable model up to isomorphism. In fact, it can be shown (by using the compactness theorem) that there are uncountably many countable models of PA!

Comment: I completely forgot to mention that the same thing happens with the field of real numbers. The second-order axiomatization is categorical, but the first-order axiomatization is not (again by compactness we can construct non-standard models). Of course, second-order logic with full semantics does not have all the nice properties like compactness and completeness.